# Convert a string to a tuple

Tags: python, string, parsing, pygame, tuples

I read some tuple data from a file.  The tuples are in string form, for example `Color["RED"] = '(255,0,0)'`.  How can I convert these strings into actual tuples?

I want to use this data in PyGame like this:

```
gameDisplay.fill(Color["RED"])
# but it doesn't have the right data right now:
gameDisplay.fill('(255,0,0)')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`literal_eval`](http://literal_eval) of the `ast` module:

> ast.**literal_eval**(*node_or_string*)
>
> Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.

Example:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("(255, 0, 0)")
(255, 0, 0)
>>>
```

---

Regarding pygame, note that the [`Color` class](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/color.html) can also take the name of a color as string:

```
>>> import pygame
>>> pygame.color.Color('RED')
(255, 0, 0, 255)
>>>
```

so maybe you could generally simplify your code.

Also, you should not name your `dict` `Color`, since there's already the `Color` class in pygame and that will only lead to confusion.

Comment: I imported more colors than pygame's one !

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) -

Example -

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval('(255,0,0)')
>>> (255, 0, 0)
```

In your case -

```
gameDisplay.fill(ast.literal_eval(Color["RED"]))
```

Please note, ast.literal_eval will evaluate the expression (which is the string) and return the result.

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) -

> ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)
>
> Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers use the `ast` module, but the same thing can be done using the built-in function `eval`.

```
>>> mystring = '(255,0,0)'
>>> eval(mystring)
(255,0,0)
```

[See the docs for more info.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval)

Comment: Yeah, `eval` works, too. But it's bad practice because it is unsafe (allows to run arbitary code), while `literal_eval` only allows strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.

Comment: i didnt realise that until i saw this question, never even knew there was an alternative, to `eval` but reading about it now it seems a good idea to avoid it.