# Converting a string to tuple -- ast.literal_eval() doesn't work

Tags: python, data-structures, tuples

I"m getting a list of strings back as an argument from arg_parse, and I would like to convert some of those strings to tuples if it is easily possible.

Here is the list I'm getting from argparse:

```
['adding_light', '(shift_right_cv,shift_left_cv)']
```

I wonder how to convert this `'(shift_right_cv,shift_left_cv)'` to a tuple.

I don't want to use `eval`, as these strings will be inputted by the user (argparse arguments).

Unfortunately, ast.literal.eval() doesn' work -- I get

```
raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x00000000036A9BA8>
>>>
```

The suggestions from these threads have been tried out ( not the complicated one):

[Parse a tuple from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763116/parse-a-tuple-from-a-string)

[Convert a string to a tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272772/convert-a-string-to-a-tuple)

If there is no easy solution, I may just turn the tuple into a list --so I will get back a nested list from argparse, and see if that is easier to handle. 
I could also use RE, but I'm concerned about properly covering all cases (user input may possibly break the code).

Thank you.

Comment: what's wrong with `tuple(my_list[optional:slice])`?

Comment: Your strings don't have quotes around them (the reason for the error). I'd recommend cleaning up each string and then tuplizing your strings yourself, instead of using `ast`.

Comment: @Moondra  If this is what you meant, you may locate those 2 consecutive list elements, and then delete the `(` from the 1st and `)` from the 2nd, and then do `thetuple = (1st, 2nd)`. Is this easy enough or else..?

Comment: "doesn't work" it works fine if you provide syntactically correct tuples, not sure what you expect when inputting malformed ones -- getting an exception saying they are malformed seems like very much *working* -- so either the user provided bad input or you simply forgot to massage the input to something that can be converted

Comment: @jonatan It's not a malformed tuple -- I fixed the placement of single quotes.

Comment: If you put `(shift_right_cv,shift_left_cv)` directly into a Python file, you would get a tuple where the first element contains whatever object the `shift_right_cv` variable points to the second element contains whatever object the `shift_left_cv` variable points to. Is that what you want? The ast` module is not capable of using local variables. You could use `eval()` if the source is trusted.

Comment: @Moondra if you are indeed trying to evaluate variables, then you're trying to use `eval`. ast.literal_eval reads *literals*, that's what makes it safe. Also consider just splitting input on comma instead of trying to convert it into data structures (if all you're looking for is a sequence of names) and then compare the input to what you want to allow